# "of the three" vs "of all three"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

If we make a sentence comparing the age of three people, we can say "A is the oldest **of the three**." At that time, would it be possible to say, "A is the oldest **of all three**." Is the sentence grammatically incorrect?

Comment: No, perfectly correct.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct. You would usually use "A is the oldest of the three" if you were talking about three people from a larger group e.g. three girls who have two brothers, while you would use "A is the oldest of all three" if there were only three in the group e.g. three girls with no brothers.